# Populate an array without a loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, populate

I am trying to **avoid the use of loops for populating arrays** since they take a lot of time when managing a lot of data.

Apparently as well, that is possible and easy in VBA but often results in problems.

Here is the code:

```
sub populate()
'put the whole column in an array
Dim AppArray() As Variant
Dim AppRange As Range
'calculate the last row of the column 1 of sheets
Dim LstRow As Integer
LstRow = Sheets("whole").Cells(Sheets("whole").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
'here I calculate the range that I want to pass to the array
Set AppRange = Sheets("whole").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LstRow, 1))
MsgBox ("apprange " & AppRange.Address)
'i dont know if I need to redim or not
ReDim AppArray(1 To LstRow)
'here comes the point. populate the array with the values of the range
AppArray = AppRange.Value
End Sub
```

This does not work. I also tried `application.tranpose(AppRange.Value)`.

I used:

```
For i = 1 To LstRow
Debug.Print AppArray(i)
Next
```

and an error appears, so somehow there is no `AppArray(1)`.

I would be very happy if you can comment on that. More than just arranging the code suggest even other pages (links) to populate arrays with values of ranges when these ranges are not known in advance.

If the case is that looping is very time consuming and that arrays can be populated straight away, I don't understand why 99% of the pages referring to arrays use a loop (or nested loop) to populate an array.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question, but performance of loops is the last thing you should worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
dim myRange as range
dim myArray() as variant
myRange = range(cells(2,3),cells(10,15))
redeem myArray(1 to 20,1 to 20)
myArray=myRange
```

It's always much faster to work with variables and arrays than with cells values.